# Bootstrap UI with ASP.NET MVC. Are there any ready made templates available?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, templates

I am working on super simple website and need to make it look good(clean and professional).
Was thinking to utilize bootstrap.

Are there any ready made templates for ASP.NET that are based on Bootstrap framework?
Just to confirm - the goal is to make the super simple website to look professional and clean, so special UI design is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would be nice if there was one available, but unfortunately all of the current MVC web templates come prepackaged with JQuery UI, and that's it.

However, there are NuGet packages available, depending on which version of MVC you're working with :

[Bootstrap for MVC 5](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Bootstrap.MVC/)

[Bootstrap for MVC 4](http://www.nuget.org/packages/twitter.bootstrap.mvc4)

Using these and some of the examples online, you should be able to get up running pretty quick.